# Nullpointer exception for AndroidImageSlider DefaultSliderView In Android Studio, Build 22.0.1

Tags: android, slider

This is my stack trace :

```
08-16 10:23:40.006  19022-19022/com.world.innov.ebilling     E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.world.innov.ebilling, PID: 19022
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.world.innov.ebilling/com.world.innov.ebilling.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.os.Bundle.putString(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.os.Bundle.putString(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
    at com.world.innov.ebilling.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:52)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

This is my activity :

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderLayout;
import com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderTypes.BaseSliderView;
import com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderTypes.BaseSliderView.OnSliderClickListener;
import com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderTypes.DefaultSliderView;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnSliderClickListener {
public static final String MY_PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";
private SliderLayout mDemoSlider;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    mDemoSlider = (SliderLayout) findViewById(R.id.slider);

    HashMap<String, Integer> file_maps = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    file_maps.put("A", R.drawable.invoicebyhand);
    file_maps.put("B", R.drawable.invoicebymobile);
    file_maps.put("C", R.drawable.analysis);

    for (String name : file_maps.keySet()) {
        DefaultSliderView defaultSliderView = new DefaultSliderView(this);
        // initialize a SliderLayout
        defaultSliderView
                .description(name)
                .image(file_maps.get(name))
                .setScaleType(BaseSliderView.ScaleType.Fit)
                .setOnSliderClickListener(this);

        //add your extra information
        defaultSliderView.getBundle()
                .putString("extra", name);

        mDemoSlider.addSlider(defaultSliderView);
    }
            mDemoSlider.setPresetTransformer(SliderLayout.Transformer.RotateUp);
    mDemoSlider.setPresetIndicator(SliderLayout.PresetIndicators.Center_Bottom);
    mDemoSlider.stopAutoCycle();


    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
    String pin = prefs.getString("pin", "");

    if (pin.equals("")) {
        disableLetsGo();
        Intent i = new Intent(this, TOCActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    } else {
        disableSignUp();
    }

}

@Override
public void onSliderClick(BaseSliderView slider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

**My question is "can anybody see why am i getting null pointer exception at line 52 for i guess defaultSliderView"?**

```
line 52 is : defaultSliderView.getBundle()
                .putString("extra", name);
```

I am using android studio with 22.0.1 buildtoolversion. I did not face this problem while i was doing this project on eclipse. This is the first time i am using android studio. I completely migrated the project with success and i am getting run time exception. I am using androidimageslider by daimajia.

**Update: defaultSliderView is returning null bundle(Thanks @HariRam). How should i proceed or is there anything to replace bundle ?**

**Update2: I removed line 52. Its now working.**

Comment: Actually when i print the value of defaultSliderView, it is not null. And name is also not null. I am actually clueless.

Comment: I think defaultSliderView.getBundle() is returning null and you are doing put on null. Can you check weather defaultSliderView.getBundle() is returning null or is it returning proper bundle?

Comment: defaultSliderView is not bull but it might not have any bundle and might be returning null when you are doing defaultSliderView.getBundle() so just check for it.

Comment: Oh my god , you are right. Thanks. What do i do ?

Comment: create a new Bundle like Bundle bundle = new Bundle() and then put whatever values you want to put then try defaultSliderView.putBundle(bundle) or any other way to set bundle in defaultSliderView.

Comment: There is no other facility to set the bundle for defaultSliderView. But why is it giving null back.

Comment: This is how i solved it : i removed the line. It made no bad effect on app. Its working now. Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87104/discussion-between-hariram-and-samo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> defaultSliderView.getBundle()

is returning null so here you are trying to put values in null bundle. Because of this your app is crashing.

> defaultSliderView.getBundle()
>                   .putString("extra", name);

removing this line is not making any bad effect on your app so you should remove it.

Answer (score 1):

this question answered already, but in my case which I need that bundle in onSliderClick, getBundle() is null because you didn't set a bundle for that. so you can do it like this:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
textSliderView.bundle(bundle);
```

so after that you can get the bundle.